# Get a filename bat

Tags: variables, date, batch-file, filesize

I am new to BAT writing.
I am trying to write a batch file which will check to see if a file is above or below a certain size and then send an email accordingly.  I have written something that can do this with a static file name

```
@echo off
setlocal
set file="ssoff.bat"
set maxbytesize=1000

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^< %maxbytesize% bytes
    blat -server mail.omers.com -f checker@omers.com -t rplomp@omers.com -s "filesize less than" -body testbody 
) ELSE (
    echo.File is ^>= %maxbytesize% bytes
    blat -server mail.omers.com -f checker@omers.com -t rplomp@omers.com -s "filesize greater than" -body testbody
)
```

In this case, the filename being checked is `ssoff.bat`.  However, I need to have the bat check a filename which changes daily according to the date.  The mask for the filename uses the date string IE: `deployEAR_restartWAS_03132013.log ; deployEAR_restartWAS_03142013.log` ... and so on - with the last 8 chars reflecting the date generated.  The bat needs to check the latest file in that directory.  For today it would be  `deployEAR_restartWAS_03152013.log`

This logfile would not be in the parent dir either.

I thought maybe of having the bat copying over the latest file from that dir to the parent dir and then checking its size?  Or using the static part of the filename   `'deployEAR_restartWAS_'` and then passing the last part of it through a `date` variable?
But I'm not sure what approach would be best, and I'm sure there are others that I have not thought of.

The bat file run time would be the same day as the date variable at the end of the filename.

Comment: why batch ?  powershell or a c#/vb console app would be far easier.

Comment: batch scripting is pretty antiquated. For your needs beginning this in powershell or even vbs would've been immensely easier and less convoluted. Both scripting languages have extensive SMTP libraries and functions, as well as integral file functions, with great readability.

Comment: @Dan-o you wrote that as I was writing the above. glad you're in the same lines of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od deployEAR_restartWAS_*.log') do set name=%%i&set size=%%~zi
echo latest file is %name% size %size%
```

Can't work out in which directory this set of `.log` files resides from your description. You tell us it won't be in `the parent directory` and your only reference appears to be `that` directory.

If the `.log` files are not in the CURRENT directory, all you need do is add the directory name to the `deploy...` thus: `Q:\wherever\it\maybe\deployEAR_restartWAS_*.log` or, if the file's path contains spaces, quote the  name thus: `"Q:\where ever\it\may be\deployEAR_restartWAS_*.log"`

Comment: You beat me by one minute.  I had a similar idea, except ordering by date instead of by name.  `FOR /F %%A IN ('dir /b /o:d "path\to\*.log"') DO set size=%%~zA`, except with the `"usebackq"` option which I can't illustrate easily in a comment....

Comment: Oh no - youre perfectly correct - it `SHOULD` be order by date since the date section is allotted in MMDDYYYY order. OP: answer has been corrected to sequence by date, not name. BUT it's standard practice to use date strings as YYYYMMDD if you can because they then can be sorted into date-sequence by simply sorting them alphabetically.